# Misspecify $ in-text

Tags: r

the following equation is kind of creating an issue when I'm typing it in-text

```
 $\frac${$\partial$ LL}{$\partial$ $\Omega$}$
```

Am I mis-specifying $ anywhere?

Comment: Hi Alexa, [welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436), you have far more `$` than necessary, the hole equation needs to be wrapped in `$` not each symbol, so this should be `$\frac{\partial LL}{\partial \Omega}$`.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your question yesterday: remove all the `$` except the first to enter math mode and the last, to leave it.